# Karate Cucumber Reports not displaying logs in html

Tags: java, html, gradle, cucumber, karate

When running Karate tests using git pipelines, the logs are visible in git pipeline logs but are not showing up in cucumber html
Java 17
Gradle 7.4
Karate 1.2.0
Cucumber Reporting 5.3

Both print and karate.log are not printing assertions, print statement etc. Is there a logging setting needed for showing karate logs in cucumber html report?

Any help provided is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging, we were able to resolve this issue after adding a logback.xml file in the project containing the karate.

Answer (score 1):

This can depend on if some other logging system has "taken over". Recently I saw this happen with Quarkus, so there was a need to "bridge" what Quarkus was using to "logback" which is what Karate uses. You may get some tips from this [sample](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/quarkus/README.md).

The other thing that comes to mind is that if the log level was forced to WARN, only DEBUG levels appear in the log.

Otherwise, sorry - it is near impossible to diagnose this without direct access to your runtime. You may need to figure this out on your own. The documentation has a section on logging, so see if that helps: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#logging